libvips to crop an image with an origin point
The goal is to take an image and generate multiple variants of an image, with a predefined height, but varying width, thus cropping based on the top,left origin point.
Selecting the libvips library for Rails' ActiveStorage, the process should be executable via the image_processing gem helpers. The gem's wiki provides pointers to this execution:
 ImageProcessing::Vips.crop(0, 0, 300, 300)
however the syntax is not being executed properly
class Pretti < ApplicationRecord
  extend Mobility
  require "image_processing/vips"

  belongs_to :shop
  
  validates :name, presence: true
  
  translates :name_locale, type: :string

#  pipeline = ImageProcessing::Vips
#    .source(file)
#    .convert("png")

#  mobile = pipeline.crop: [0, 0, 90, 480]
#  medium = pipeline.crop: [0, 0, 90, 780]
#  small  = pipeline.crop: [0, 0, 90, 1280]

  has_one_attached :background_image do |attachable|
    attachable.variant :mobile, ImageProcessing::Vips.crop: [0, 0, 90, 480]
    attachable.variant :tablet, ImageProcessing::Vips.crop: [0, 0, 90, 780]
    attachable.variant :desktop,  ImageProcessing::Vips.crop: [0, 0, 90, 1280]
  end
end

The logged error is
NameError (uninitialized constant ImageProcessing::Vips):
referring to the third line of the class definition.
If the require line is commented out, then the error is:
uninitialized constant ImageProcessing::Vips
[..]
attachable.variant :mobile, ImageProcessing::Vips.crop(0, 0, 90, 480)

the commented lines were from a separate attempt, where the syntax was lifted from the documentation
How should this be cast?

In case anyone comes across this issue...
At time of writing, various documentary sources (rails guide, edge guides, image_processing gem) are potentially misleading.
The present situation is rather neat and tidy. No require needed and the syntax appears homogenised between dependancy processors.  Thus:
#   require "image_processing/vips"

  has_one_attached :background_image do |attachable|
    attachable.variant :mobile, crop: [0, 0, 480, 90], preprocessed: true
    attachable.variant :tablet, crop: [0, 0, 780, 90], preprocessed: true
    attachable.variant :desktop, crop: [0, 0, 1280, 90], preprocessed: true
  end

